# Highcharts: How to pass the color parameter with data and dates to the bar chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I read the data from the sensor and display the values in the chart, 
using the Highcharts library.

In my AngularJS controller I prepare the data and pass them to the chart (relevant part of the code):

```
... 
var measurementData = [];   
$scope.setGraphValues = function () {
    ...
    var data = $scope.tableData;
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        measurementData.push([Date.UTC(yearPart, monthPart,
            dayPart, hourPart, minutePart),data[i].sensorsData]);
    }
    ...
    $scope.highchartsNG.series[0].data = measurementData;
}
```

Some of the data have errors and I want to display them in other color, for example.

How can I do it? How can I pass the color parameter to the charts data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can push data objects into measurementData like this:

```
{
    "x":Date.UTC(yearPart, monthPart,
             dayPart, hourPart, minutePart),
    "y":data[i].sensorsData,
    "color": yourColorHere
}
```

Comment: @AlekseyBykov currently I am writing it hardcoded and it works, not sure about dynamic insertion of data